# alter css on another div not working as it is not in the same element

Tags: html, css

`#match1` Will not change when I hover over `#id1`? It worked when they where both in the same div element on the page but now stops working when the `#id1` is inside another div.

I only want to use CSS no javascript please!

http://jsfiddle.net/fHZEN/

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="id1">DIV</div> 
    <div id="id2">DIV</div> 
    <div id="id3">DIV</div> 
</div>


<div id="match1">a </div>
<div id="match2">b </div>
<div id="match3">c </div>
```

CSS

```
#id1:hover ~ #match3 {
  color: red;  
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **preceding selector**

The preceding selector targets a precedent element with the same parent as the one of the target
So , if you want to target match3 div being preceed by id1 the markup should be as follows

```
<div>
    <div id="id1">DIV</div> 
    <div id="id2">DIV</div> 
    <div id="id3">DIV</div> 
    <div id="match1">a </div>
    <div id="match2">b </div>
    <div id="match3">c </div>
</div>
```

BUT...
In spite of that, if what you are looking for is to target both (match3 & id1)  when you hover id1, you wont be able to do it without javascript

This is because you have a single subject and it is targeted with the right most simple selector in the selector chain.

```
#id1:hover ~ #match3 {
  color: red;  
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133145/sven-bieder) didn't answer the question. The user asked to create the effect on a different div, not the one hovered.

The `~`, `+` and `>` operators will only work when a relation can be established between the different containers. This is why when they're both in the same `div` or in the `<body>` it works properly, but otherwise doesn't work at all.

Unfortunately, from what I can tell, you'll need to use more complicated scripts to get this kind of thing to work, or force them to share the same container (if possible).